# ASP Net MVC, Server Error in '/' Application - The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently get the error "The Resource cannot be found" when trying to access a View.

The View I am trying to open is called "Register".
The Controller(AccountController) has the ActionResult Method "Register" implemented.

The same Controller contains a "Login" View that I can access without any problems.

The URLS I am trying to call:

localhost:port/Account/Login <- Works
localhost:port/Account/Register <- Doesnt work

Controller Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(LoginModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            movieEntities db = new movieEntities();
            var newUser = db.users.Create();
            var encrypPass = Helpers.SHA256.Encode(model.Passwort);
            var user = model.UserName;
            newUser.user_name = user;
            newUser.user_passwdhash = encrypPass;
            db.users.Add(newUser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model MovieDatabase.Models.LoginModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Register</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>LoginModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class 
    = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = 
    new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Passwort, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Passwort, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Passwort, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Register="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
    @section Scripts {
         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

I tried cleaning, rebuilding the solution, renaming the View, renaming the method and creating them new...
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your method that you're calling is POST back try to create another method that will return the view that you are referring to. Add this on your code.

```
 public ActionResult Register()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

> The file name of the view is same of the name of your method. If
>   not you're getting the same error.

For more info in routing kindly refer to Microsoft documentation [ASP.NET MVC Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: Thank you! i didnt think of that... Fixed it